# RestSharp Serializing Json objects to Post parameters

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp, http-post

I'm working on this project that needs to serialize JSON objects to post parameters using RestSharp, below is my code:

```
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        request.AddBody(jsonObject);
        return client.Execute<dynamic>(request);
```

What I realize is instead of adding each JSON name value pair as a post parameter, `request.AddBody` adds the whole JSON string as one large post parameter. My question is, is there any way to cause `request.AddBody` method to add each JSON name-value pair as individual post parameters? I know that `request.AddParameter()` does the job but that requires manual effort to add each parameter.

Instead of:

```
     [0]:{
           application/json="
           {
               "name":"john doe",
               "age": "12",
               "gender": "male"}
           }
         }
```

Desired Result:

```
     [0]:"name":"john doe"
     [1]:"age":"12"
     [2]:"gender":"male"
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to accomplish?  Show us what you're starting with and what you want the end result to be.

Comment: I don't understand the format of your "desired result" - it doesn't seem like a standard format for the body of a POST request. Something  like `?name=john doe&age=12&gender=male` would be more normative. Can you just confirm if that is the kind of thing you had in mind?

Comment: @DanielC, yes, it is exactly what i want. but instead of having a foreach loop to add the individual parameter, i was just wondering is there any solution in JSON.net which can convert the all the json into something like ?name=john doe&age=12&gender=male

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would seem to be to iterate through your `jsonObject` and turn each desired JSON name-value pair into a parameter. To do this you can use the `request.AddParameter` method in a loop which iterates through the name-value pairs of your `jsonObject` with something like:

```
foreach (var pair in jsonObject) 
{ 
    request.AddParameter(pair.Key, pair.Value); 
}
```

This is probably oversimplified, but using a library like JSON.NET, it should be quite easy to do. Then you can wrap this functionality into a nice little method somewhere and reuse at will. No manual labour.

NB: You probably want to remove the line `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json` in your existing code, since JSON is exactly what you don't appear to want to POST.

Comment: thanks daniel, i guess this would be the only solution for now.

Answer (score 5):

```
request.AddObject(jsonObject)
```

should do what you expect

Quote from [RestSharp docs](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage):

> To add all properties for an object as parameters, use AddObject().

Comment: You should include why this should do as expected. This is a weak answer without an explanation.

Comment: That's basically a replacement for loop above, doing AddParameter() for each field inside the jsonObject.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar question and found this thread.  Came up with a simple approach that I thought I would share in case it would help others.

The trick is to use anonymous objects along with AddJsonBody().

```
request.AddJsonBody(new { name = "john doe", age = "12", gender = "male" });
```

RestSharp will automatically serialize the anonymous object into the desired JSON...

```
{
    "name":"john doe",
    "age": "12",
    "gender": "male"
}
```